# Concatenating data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I have scraped some tables from Yahoo finance and I've tried concatenating them into one data frame but I'm getting an error message:

"ValueError: No objects to concatenate"

Here's the script:

```
CalendarDays = 3 #<-- specify the number of calendar days you want to grab earnings release info for
tables = [] #<-- initialize an empty list to store your tables

for i in trange(CalendarDays, file = sys.stdout, desc = 'Grabbing companies with earnings releases in the next ' + str(CalendarDays) + ' days'):

    for i in range(CalendarDays): #<-- Grabs earnings release info for the next x days on the calendar
        try: 
            date = (datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days = i )).isoformat() #get tomorrow in iso format as needed'''
            pd.set_option('display.max_column',None)
            url = pd.read_html("https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day="+date, header=0)
            table = url[0]
            table['Earnings Release Date'] = date
            tables.append(table) #<-- append each table into your list of tables
        except ValueError:
            continue

df = pd.concat(tables, ignore_index = True) #<-- take your list of tables into 1 final dataframe
```

Comment: FVIW your code worked for me just fine without any changes (well, added a couple of imports). Got a df of (39,7) shape. Either you had some internet problems at the time :-) or old pandas? worth checking their version perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are 2 loops that seems to me to repeat the same task.
`for i in trange(CalendarDays...):`  and `for i in range(CalendarDays):`

all the rest in the code works OK. Try to take longer period for testing. Not each day earnings are released. I have tested for 6 days and 4 were with data.  For day without earnings release no table is returned and you effectively mute this error with `try... except:...`  block.

However in case all 3 days consecutive days have no release, your list contains null tables and script ends abruptly.

You can test for this condition with `if ... else...`  block as this can happen frequently and exit script gracefully